# vi dot doesn't work

Tags: vim, vi, netrw, yadr

After I installed YADR, I cannot use vi <kbd>.</kbd> command.

If I use vi <kbd>.</kbd> command, my macbook's vim just says

> "." is a directory
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

I want to open netrw browser when I open directory by vim.

I think the problem comes from my vimrc file: https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: If you are positive the issue didn't exist before you installed YADR, please use YADR's issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you romainl, I  checked it now, and I found some guys like me. They don't have a solution yet.

Comment: "YADR" as in "Yet Another Dotfiles Repository"? I'm *not* touching this!

Comment: I agree with @Ben, you would be better following some [guide like this](https://danielmiessler.com/study/vim/#configuration).

Comment: Don't install random configuration files you don't understand. Sure, they're useful to read and use as an inspiration, but mindless copying *will* lead to problems (as you've just discovered).